# Slick 3.0 Custom Code Generation for Oracle

Tags: oracle, scala, sbt, slick, slick-3.0

I am trying to generate Slick 3.0 code for Oracle. The DB user points to two schemas that have tables with the same name so the generated code has duplicate classes. I would like to filter out the tables from the schema that end in "STAGE"

Here is the code:

```
object CodeGen2 extends App {
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285129/slick-code-generation-for-only-a-single-schema

  val slickDriver = "com.typesafe.slick.driver.oracle.OracleDriver"
  val jdbcDriver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
  val url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbhost:1521:dbsid"
  val user = "dbuser"
  val password = "dbpassword"
  val destDir = "src/main/scala"
  val destPackage = "com.mycompany.mypackage"

  import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Await, Future}
  import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
  import slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder
  import slick.jdbc.meta.MTable
  import com.typesafe.slick.driver.oracle.OracleDriver
  import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.DatabaseFactoryDef


  println("Starting codegen...")
  val db = OracleDriver.simple.Database.forURL(url, user=user, password=password, driver=jdbcDriver)
  val filteredTables = OracleDriver.defaultTables.filter(
        (t: MTable) => !t.name.schema.get.endsWith("STAGE")
      )

  val modelAction = OracleDriver.createModel(filteredTables, true)
  println("Generating model...")
  val model = Await.result(db.run(modelAction), Duration.Inf)
  val codegen = new SourceCodeGenerator(model) {
    // for illustration
    val noStage = model.tables.filter { table => !table.name.schema.get.endsWith("STAGE") } 
    noStage.foreach { table => println(table.name.schema.get) }

  }
  println("Generating files...")
  codegen.writeToFile(
    slickDriver, destDir, destPackage, "Tables", "Tables.scala"
  )
//  slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator.main(
//    Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, destDir, destPackage, user, password)
//  )
  println("Finished codegen.")
}
```

I try and filter the defaultTables but the signature is Seq[MTable] => Boolean so I have no idea how to deal with that. Is filtering the tables passed to driver.createModel the correct approach? I looked and tried other code with override(n) methods but nothing seemed workable.

```
name := "slick-test"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.0",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-extensions" % "3.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.0.0"
)

resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way :

```
 val filteredTables = OracleDriver.defaultTables.map(seq => seq.filter(t => !t.name.schema.get.endsWith("STAGE")))
  val modelAction = OracleDriver.createModel(Option(filteredTables), true)
```

Comment: Thanks @bhavya, this worked perfectly exactly as you posted. The generated code does not compile now but that is a separate problem.

Answer (score 2):

Update: After I posted above, a workaround was found to the code generation problem for Oracle. It should be fixed in Slick 3.2. Replace the code above with this SourceCodeGenerator. See https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1000

```
val codegen = new SourceCodeGenerator(model) {
  // slated for fix in 3.2
  override def Table = new Table(_) { table =>
    // override generator responsible for columns
    override def Column = new Column(_) {
      override def defaultCode = v => {
        def raw(v: Any) = rawType match {
          case "String" => "\"" + v + "\""
          case "Long" => v + "L"
          case "Float" => v + "F"
          case "Char" => "'" + v + "'"
          case "scala.math.BigDecimal" => v.toString.trim + "d"
          case "Byte" | "Short" | "Int" | "Double" | "Boolean" => v.toString
        }
        v match {
          case Some(x) => s"Some(${raw(x)})"
          case None    => "None"
          case x       => raw(x)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```